# form_submit hook not firing

Tags: hooks, forms

The title says it all. I've created a form, but the submit hook isn't triggered once the form is submitted.

```
    <?php

//Create raffle form
function raffle_create_form()
{

    //Basic raffle info
    $form['#method'] = 'post';
    $form['raf_raffle_name'] = array(
        '#type' => "textfield",
        "#prefix" => "<h5>Raffle information</h5><hr>",
        "#title" => "Raffle Name:",
        "#required" => TRUE
    );

    $form['raf_allowed_number'] = array(
        '#type' => "textfield",
        "#title" => "How many people can join this raffle?",
        "#required" => TRUE
    );

    $form['raf_start_now'] = array(
        "#type" => "checkbox",
        "#title" => "Start raffle now?"
    );

    $form['raf_end_date'] = array(
        "#type" => "date",
        "#title" => "When to close this raffle?",
        "#required" => TRUE
    );


    $form['raf_prize_type'] = array(
        '#type' => "select",
        "#options" => array('gift' => 'Steam Gift', 'hardware' => 'Gaming peripherals'),
        "#prefix" => "<h4>Prize information</h4><hr>",
        "#title" => "Prize type",
        "#required" => TRUE
    );

    $form['raf_prize_name'] = array(
        '#type' => "textfield",
        "#title" => "Prize name",
        "#required" => TRUE
    );

    $form['raf_prize_about'] = array(
        '#type' => "textarea",
        "#resizeable" => true,
        "#title" => "Prize description"
    );

    $form['raf_prize_thumb'] = array(
        '#type' => "file",
        "#title" => "Prize thumbnail"
    );

    $form['raf_prize_link'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => "Link to product"
    );

    $form['raf_raffle_create'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => "Create Raffle",
    );

    $form['#submit'][] = 'raffle_create_form_submit';
    return $form;
}

function raffle_create_form_validate()
{
    //validation logic
}

function raffle_create_form_submit()
{
    print_r($_POST);
}
```

Isn't the submit hook supposed to fire automatically?

What i'm doing now is i've set an action to a particular URL, made the menu hook call drupal_form_submit and passed the raffle_create_form_submit as an argument.

```
    <?php

//Create raffle form
function raffle_create_form()
{

    //Basic raffle info

    $form['#action'] = url('/admin/config/people/raffle/create/post');
    $form['raf_raffle_name'] = array(
        '#type' => "textfield",
        "#prefix" => "<h5>Raffle information</h5><hr>",
        "#title" => "Raffle Name:",
        "#required" => TRUE
    );

    $form['raf_allowed_number'] = array(
        '#type' => "textfield",
        "#title" => "How many people can join this raffle?",
        "#required" => TRUE
    );

    $form['raf_start_now'] = array(
        "#type" => "checkbox",
        "#title" => "Start raffle now?"
    );

    $form['raf_end_date'] = array(
        "#type" => "date",
        "#title" => "When to close this raffle?",
        "#required" => TRUE
    );

    $form['raf_prize_type'] = array(
        '#type' => "select",
        "#options" => array('gift' => 'Steam Gift', 'hardware' => 'Gaming peripherals'),
        "#prefix" => "<h4>Prize information</h4><hr>",
        "#title" => "Prize type",
        "#required" => TRUE
    );

    $form['raf_prize_name'] = array(
        '#type' => "textfield",
        "#title" => "Prize name",
        "#required" => TRUE
    );

    $form['raf_prize_about'] = array(
        '#type' => "textarea",
        "#resizeable" => true,
        "#title" => "Prize description"
    );

    $form['raf_prize_thumb'] = array(
        '#type' => "file",
        "#title" => "Prize thumbnail"
    );

    $form['raf_prize_link'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => "Link to product"
    );

    $form['raf_raffle_create'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => "Create Raffle",
    );

    $form['#submit'][] = 'raffle_create_form_submit';
    return $form;
}

function raffle_create_form_validate()
{
    //validation logic
}

function raffle_create_form_submit()
{
    print_r($_POST);
}



//Menu hook
```

function raffle_menu()
{
    $items = array();

```
$items['admin/config/people/raffle'] = array(
    'title' => 'Raffle',
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('Manage Raffles'),
    'file' => 'raffle_admin.inc',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('raffle_admin_page')
);

$items['admin/config/people/raffle/create'] = array(
    'title' => 'Create Raffle',
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('Manage Raffles'),
    'file' => 'raffle_admin.inc',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('raffle_create_form')
);

$items['admin/config/people/raffle/create/post'] = array(
    'title' => 'Creating Raffle!',
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('Manage Raffles'),
    'file' => 'raffle_admin.inc',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_form_submit',
    'page arguments' => array('raffle_create_form_submit')
);
return $items;
```

}

Is this the way it should be done?

Comment: Instead of `print_r()` to check your submit handler is called, use `watchdog()`. Also, it's not that the way to redirect users after they submitted a form.

Comment: I removed the action attribute and menu hook for the redirect, and tried watchdog(); and my hook is being fired. Thanks. Please post it as an answer so i can accept it

Comment: Why get values from $_POST ? :S _form_submit should have a $form and a &$form_state arguments right?

Comment: @GianniDiFalco sorry, im new to Drupal and i've been trying to figure my way around it. And it seems the second argument of the submit hook has the necessary data i need. Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 1):

@Haider Ali, Drupal form need to be defined with the $form, $form_state arguments

```
  function your_form_name($form, &$form_state) { }
```

For validate and submit function, you need to define them with function name following _validate and _submit respectively. So your validate function should be like

```
  function your_form_name_validate($form, &$form_state) { }
```

and submit function:

```
  function your_form_name_submit($form, &$form_state) { }
```

If form, and related functions are defined in this way, then only validate  and submit function will be called by default. Else they will not be called.